# How to center div element in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following code:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/TomsStyleSheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="centerBlock">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CcsClass="center">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="centerBlock">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Directory Path: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" Width="200px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="checksumBtn" runat="server" Text="Calculate Checksum" OnClick="CalculateChecksum" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="errorMsg" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="error"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the css:

```
.centerBlock
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is simply center it... horizontally for now but vertically would also be good so it's smack dab in the middle of the page.

I know that it's not a problem of referencing the external style sheet because CssClass="error" on the last line works fine. I've also tried `<div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">` as according to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616112/how-to-center-one-div-in-form) but nothing seems to work. The output is currently left-justified, not centered. I'm using IE 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, simply refreshing the browser seemed to solve my problem. I noticed that when I updated my CSS, it wasn't acknowledging the changed values in the web browser - when I did Right-Click > Inspect Element in Chrome, it still showed the old values, even after stopping debugging, stopping the server, or quitting and reopening Visual Studio.

I did a search and came across [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563648/visual-studio-development-server-not-updating-css-and-javascript) which let me know that the problem lay with the browser.

Answer (score 4):

If you want it to be exactly in the middle of the page, try this:

```
.centerBlock {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -25%;
}
```

See this [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9Eych/).

You will obviously need to adjust the height and top margin accordingly.

Comment: this isn't working for me either. Tried switching to Chrome too and still doesn't work

Comment: Are the styles being applied? You can check in Chrome's Element Inspector.

Comment: it doesn't look like it... when i select that div, under "Styles > Matched CSS Rules" it shows this: div { display: block; }, but for my other error class (which is working) it displays the proper css

Comment: Then the CSS styles aren't being applied.

Comment: but why? I edited the post to show all my entire aspx page. Maybe the problem is somewhere in there?

Comment: Without seeing a demo link, it's hard to diagnose. Have a peek around in Chrome Developer Tools, they include a Resources tab that should tell you what's loaded, and what's not.

Comment: thanks, after refreshing the browser, your solution works now.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-margins only work in Internet Explorer when it is in standards mode. In quirks mode it will emulate IE 5 and not support them.

Add a Doctype that will trigger standards mode. e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

See also [Wikipedia: Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode)

Comment: I have this doctype already: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> Tried substituting mine for yours and still no luck

Comment: All else being equal, that should centre it then.